# IE9: radio button selection fails with Infopath forms

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, selection, infopath, internet-explorer-9

After upgrading to IE9, InfoPath forms consistently fail on radio button selection.

This occurrs even when using compatibility mode.

[image: IE 9 InfoPath Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I have found is to replace radio buttons with checkboxes and use rules to simulate the exclusive behavior of radio buttons.  It isn't ideal at all, but one possible solution that I have found.